# Как нажать на кнопку через js?

Tags: javascript

Сама кнопка, что потребуется сделать чтобы на неё нажать через js

```
<a href="/profile-posts/1823035/react?reaction_id=1" class="reaction reaction--small actionBar-action actionBar-action--reaction reaction--imageHidden reaction--1" data-reaction-id="1" data-xf-init="reaction" data-reaction-list="< .message | .js-reactionsList" id="js-XFUniqueId5"><i aria-hidden="true"></i><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" class="reaction-sprite js-reaction" alt="Мне нравится" title="Мне нравится"> <span class="reaction-text js-reactionText"><bdi>Мне нравится</bdi></span></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const linkA = document.querySelector('a.btn.btn-unical');

linkA.click();
```

```html
<a href="https://css-tricks.com/" class="btn btn-unical">Кликай</a>
```